# ASP.NET MVC 2 Paging Sorting filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, filtering, data-paging

This may be duplicate question but I could not find one on SO. If so Please point me to the one.

I have seen many examples of Paging and Sorting using IQueryable all fine, but, I dont want to use IQueryable or at least not from outside Repository ( not expose it outside).

I am not using Linq To SQL. 
My Repository currently returns DTO or ICollection.

I am using JqGrid. I don't want to bring down all data at one time.

As my application is current in development I bring all data and then  do Paging, orderBy , SKIP, where  etc.. in controller.

what I would Like is to have these operation done at Database Level (where I believe it will be more efficient as size of database increases).

Any suggestions on how I should go about implementing Paging , Sorting and Filtering

Regards,

Mar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using your own DAL then I'm not sure what kind of advice somebody could give.  99% of paging is what you do in the data layer.  The rest is simply using url variables to send these commands down to the data layer.

Usually Browse/Grid/Collection/Bulk actions are something like this:

```
public ActionResult Browse( string search, int page, string sortedBy )
{
      var dataz = MyDAL.GetResults( search, page, sortedBy );
}
```

The rest is up to you really.

Comment: I agree with you. I think I was unnecessarily looking to complicate things by implementing  pagination, filtering ... library like Ipagination for my DataAccess layer. Looking further into it I will for now stick with the way you have described above (or till I can ask a clearer question :-))